# Does basic SAML Propagation require trust to be established?

Tags: saml, trust

I have a scenario where my service which is an OSB need to act as a pure-passthrough service for a client sending a SAML token to a Service requiring the token.
We are using **wss10_saml_token_service_policy** on OSB Proxy Service and **wss10_saml_token_client_policy** on OSB Business Service.

My question is, for this simple token, do we require to establish a trust (importing my certificate to the Server Keystore, and client's certificate into my keystore)?

I know if SSL related policies or message encryption related policies are used, trust is to be established. But is it required for this policy?

Comment: Please add tags with the environment you are using. That will make it easier to give a correct answer and also increase chances people will find and look at your question

Answer (score 0):

FYI,
a simple SAML token doesn't require trust establishment. It simply checks for the subject in the assertion, and validates against the underlying LDAP, and if exists, it passes through.

Only message protection policies require trust establishment - importing certificates, registering keys in the keystores, etc.